# How to modify my trigger to cope with bulk update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Inherited some work and have created a trigger. From what I've read I have done stuff I shouldn't have (declared variable etc) but the trigger works for update that affect one row only. If the update affects more than one row it fails.

Basically the trigger stores the 'deleted old/previous' values of specific fields from tblMachine into tblAudit.

My Trigger is...

```
    USE [MyDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_StatusChange_tblMachine]    Script Date: 12/07/2017 09:00:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_StatusChange_tblMachine] ON [dbo].[tblMachine]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN 

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;

    DECLARE @NewStatus nvarchar(20);
    DECLARE @OldStatus nvarchar(20);
    DECLARE @ChangeMade nvarchar(50);

    IF UPDATE (MachineStatus)
        BEGIN           

            SET @NewStatus = (SELECT i.MachineStatus FROM inserted i FULL OUTER JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID);
            SET @OldStatus = (SELECT d.MachineStatus FROM deleted d FULL OUTER JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = d.ID);
            SET @ChangeMade = CONCAT ( @OldStatus, '-', @NewStatus );

            -- Status Changed
            IF @OldStatus <> @NewStatus
                BEGIN

                    INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
                    DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
                    SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate ,(datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
                    i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, i.DismantledDate, 
                    CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, @ChangeMade, i.ChangedBy
                    FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d
                    ON i.MachineName = d.MachineName
                    WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe';

                END;

            -- NO STATUS CHANGE
            IF @OldStatus = @NewStatus
                BEGIN
                    -- NO STATUS CHANGE
                    -- Service Check may have changed!

                    -- INSERT INTO AUDIT IF ServiceCheck has changed AND MachineStatus is NOT DecommissionedX or Dismantled.

                    INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
                    DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
                    SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate, (datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
                    i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, (SELECT getdate() AS DismantledDate), 
                    CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, 'SC Changed - Status Not Changed', i.ChangedBy
                    FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d
                    ON i.MachineName = d.MachineName
                    WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe' And i.ServiceCheck <> d.ServiceCheck 
                    AND (i.MachineStatus <> 'DecommissionedX' AND i.MachineStatus <> 'Dismantled');

                END;

        END;

END
```

From my searches I have discovered that Triggers fire once per statement and not per row affected. I have read that a trigger can be modified to check how many rows are being updated and then use this information to do actions based on each row. Unfortunately I have not found a way to do this that I understand.

My forte is web front-end coding and my SQLServer coding is limited. The code needs to be in SQL and not the front end as there are some other tools that update these records apart from a web front-end.

Any help in adapting this trigger so that it also copes with multiple update in one statement would be appreciated.

Comment: Your searches should have already turned up plenty of examples.  Do you have a more specific, focused question about them that doesn't sound like you're trying to get somebody to do your work for you for free?

Comment: My searches did but not that I could understand enough to be able to implement. Some were using Cursor which I have read can hit performance.

Comment: Whats with the SET XACT_ABORT on? This will cancel all the remaining statements in a transaction if there is an error. I don't see a transaction or error handling.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits That proves that I have lillte SQL knowledge.. This came from the base code I found and adapted... I'll look into this and either remove or add some error handling... Thanks

Comment: It will take a little time but its really worth it to work through Error Handling and Transaction Handling by Sommarskog. http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html. You will understand a lot more about TSQL and move ever closer to being a real pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this may not be the BEST option, but one way to solve this would be to use a temp table to store which machine changed and then join to the inserted or deleted table.  Such as:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_StatusChange_tblMachine] ON [dbo].[tblMachine]
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN 

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ROWCOUNT 0;

CREATE TABLE #tmp(MachineName nvarchar(50), NewStatus nvarchar(20) NULL, OldStatus nvarchar(20) NULL)

INSERT INTO #tmp(MachineName, NewStatus) 
   SELECT MachineName,MachineStatus from inserted

UPDATE #tmp SET OldStatus = d.MachineStatus
 From deleted d 
 INNER JOIN #tmp t on t.MachineName = d.MachineName

---You could delete from #tmp where OldStatus is null to ensure this was an update


        -- Status Changed
                INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
                DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
                SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate ,(datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
                i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, i.DismantledDate, 
                CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, @ChangeMade, i.ChangedBy
                FROM inserted i JOIN #tmp t
                ON i.MachineName = t.MachineName and t.NewStatus <> t.OldStatus
                WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe' ;

                -- NO STATUS CHANGE
                -- Service Check may have changed!

                -- INSERT INTO AUDIT IF ServiceCheck has changed AND MachineStatus is NOT DecommissionedX or Dismantled.

                INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
                DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
                SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate, (datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
                i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, (SELECT getdate() AS DismantledDate), 
                CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, 'SC Changed - Status Not Changed', i.ChangedBy
                FROM inserted i JOIN #tmp t
                ON i.MachineName = t.MachineName and t.OldStatus = t.NewStatus
                WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe' And i.ServiceCheck <> d.ServiceCheck 
                AND (i.MachineStatus <> 'DecommissionedX' AND i.MachineStatus <> 'Dismantled');

 END
```

Again you will need to check the syntax as I am just modifying your code, but this is the gist of the idea.

Comment: thanks.. I can see your thinking around this... Would I need to drop table #tmp? Or should I create the table outside the trigger and then just trucate at the end of each trigger? Or is #tmp a virtual table that clears itself?

Comment: you should drop it at the end of the trigger.

Comment: great... I'll give this a go but still trying to get my head around why using a #tmp table which seems to be virtual table would be any different than using the inserted/deleted table which are also virtual tables... Giving it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it. The trick is to just use MachineStatus from your inserted and deleted tables directly in the insert into your audit table rather than trying to calculate a universal old and new status up front.

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_StatusChange_tblMachine]    Script Date: 12/07/2017 09:00:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_StatusChange_tblMachine] ON [dbo].[tblMachine]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN 

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;

    IF UPDATE (MachineStatus)
        BEGIN           

            INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
            DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
            SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate ,(datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
            i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, i.DismantledDate, 
            CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, CONCAT(d.MachineStatus, '-', i.MachineStatus), i.ChangedBy
            FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d
            ON i.MachineName = d.MachineName
            WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe'
            -- Status Changed
            AND i.MachineStatus <> d.MachineStatus;


            -- NO STATUS CHANGE
            -- Service Check may have changed!

            -- INSERT INTO AUDIT IF ServiceCheck has changed AND MachineStatus is NOT DecommissionedX or Dismantled.

            INSERT INTO dbo.tblAudit (InsertedDate, Month, Year, SupportTeam, MachineName, MachineStatus, 
            DateBuilt, DismantledDate, ServiceCheck, ServiceCheckBit, ChangeMade, ChangedBy)
            SELECT getdate() AS InsertedDate, (datepart(month,getdate())) AS Month, (datepart(Year,getdate())) AS Year, 
            i.SupportTeam, i.MachineName, i.MachineStatus, i.DateBuilt, (SELECT getdate() AS DismantledDate), 
            CASE i.ServiceCheck WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ServiceCheck, i.ServiceCheck, 'SC Changed - Status Not Changed', i.ChangedBy
            FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d
            ON i.MachineName = d.MachineName
            WHERE i.SupportTeamID <> 'mbe' And i.ServiceCheck <> d.ServiceCheck 
            AND (i.MachineStatus <> 'DecommissionedX' AND i.MachineStatus <> 'Dismantled')
            -- NO STATUS CHANGE
            AND (i.MachineStatus = d.MachineStatus);


        END;

END
```

Comment: Good but no cigar... An improvement on my code but again this will only work if the update statement affects a single row. From what I've learnt [@NewStatus], [@OldStatus] and [@ChangeMade] can't have more than one value at a time... In an Update where only one Machine is updated this works. Where there is more although the machines are updated to one status their [@OldStatus] could have different values.

Comment: You're right. But, if you examine the code, you'll see that those variables aren't used anymore after my changes. I just forgot to remove them from your code.